# How to fit a input box inside the td tag that takes most space of td?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

Here I provide a sample of my code where the input box is small inside the table. To get clear idea please run this snippet. I am trying to fit the input box inside the table so that it take whole space of td. But I can not do it! How can I do it?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <title>How to fit input box inside td tag in my way?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="table-responsive">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Experties/Skills *</h3>
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="employeeStatusTable">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th style="max-width: 10%">#</th>
                          <th style="max-width: 30%">Technology Category</th>
                          <th style="max-width: 60%">Names</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                       
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>Category 1</td>
                                <td>                                 
                                        <select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple  name="select1" class="chosen-select" >
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option>Option1</option>
                                            <option>Option2</option>
                                            <option>Option3</option>
                                            <option>Option4</option>
                                            <option>Option5</option>
                                        </select>                                  
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Category 2</td>
                                <td>                                  
                                        <select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple  name="select2" class="chosen-select" >
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option>Option1</option>
                                            <option>Option2</option>
                                            <option>Option3</option>
                                            <option>Option4</option>
                                            <option>Option5</option>
                                        </select>                                  
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
})
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I use bootstrap-5, jquery2. How can it be fitted inside the table as expected?

Comment: What do you mean with that the input does not fit inside the td?

Comment: Looks like the input is enclosed within the td in your example.

Comment: I want fit input box as whole place of td

Comment: @ArafatRahman have you tried with `.chosen-container {width: 100%!important;}`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `width: "100%"` to chosen JS like below

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
  width: "100%"
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <title>How to fit input box inside td tag in my way?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="table-responsive">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Experties/Skills *</h3>
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="employeeStatusTable">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th style="max-width: 10%">#</th>
                          <th style="max-width: 30%">Technology Category</th>
                          <th style="max-width: 60%">Names</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                       
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>Category 1</td>
                                <td>                                 
                                        <select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple  name="select1" class="chosen-select" >
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option>Option1</option>
                                            <option>Option2</option>
                                            <option>Option3</option>
                                            <option>Option4</option>
                                            <option>Option5</option>
                                        </select>                                  
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Category 2</td>
                                <td>                                  
                                        <select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple  name="select2" class="chosen-select" >
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option>Option1</option>
                                            <option>Option2</option>
                                            <option>Option3</option>
                                            <option>Option4</option>
                                            <option>Option5</option>
                                        </select>                                  
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
  width: "100%"
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```